# Evento para input type color

Tags: c#, html5, css3

Tengo en un editor de texto un boton type color para cambiar el color de letra pero no he podido ejecutar el evento, adjunto el código:

```html
<input id="Color_Letra" runat="server" name="color" type="color" value="#000000" onchange="Pintar"/>
```

Este es el evento:

```html
 protected void Pintar()
{
   textbox_titulo.Attributes.Add("style", "color:" + Color_Letra.Value);
}
```

También lo he intentado con parámetros (object sender, EventArgs e) pero nada funciona, agradezco de antemano.
[image: Captura del editor el botón con la gota cambia el color de letra.]

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar un evento javascript. Creo que algo como esto te servirá.

https://codepen.io/zeross/pen/zWoYOp